# Timediff result decimal issue oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to get number like below.

---

Ex.

Atime 20200803 180000

Btike 20200803 183000

```
Select (to_date(atime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') -to_date(btime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))*24

From dual
```

---

The result of above to be 0.5, but the output is 0.499999 .

If I use round oracle function I think it will be solved.
But I'm so curious about this.

I tried to search for this reason using keyword like 'timediff issue in oracle, timediff decimal issue in oracle', but I can't find the reason..

Why the result like this?
Or could you tell me the keyword for searching reason?

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: how so? you only need to change `set numwitdth 42`

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez sorry i couldnt solve my problem it was just format changed(0.5), and oracle has the value 0.49999 yet. I  dont want to show this just format, but why oracle has the value 0.49999

Comment: did you change the numwitdth ?  if you want  to show 0.5, change your numwidth to 42. If you want 0.49999999999 , leave as it is. I honestly don't know what is the issue. In my example yesterday, I updated the answer with the two outputs, one 0.5, the other 0.499999, as I changed  to `set numwitdth 39`

Comment: Ok wait for me plz? :) I will update my question why im not solved yet in weekly.(maybe Sunday)

Comment: I choose your answer because I think the issue of mine will be post new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are obtaining is the arithmetic difference, which is the decimal representation of that difference in number format, which has nothing to do with the time difference in terms of minutes or hours.

Let me show you an example

```
SQL> select to_date('20200803183000','yyyymmddhh24miss') - to_date('20200803173000','yyyymmddhh24miss') from dual ;

TO_DATE('20200803183000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('20200803173000','YYYYMMDDH
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                      .041666667
```

The query above is calculating the time difference between two dates, but the output is the decimal representation in numeric format,  which I can translate into minutes

```
SQL> select ( to_date('20200803183000','yyyymmddhh24miss') - to_date('20200803173000','yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 * 60 from dual ;

(TO_DATE('20200803183000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('20200803173000','YYYYMMDD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                              60

SQL>
```

If you want in hours

```
SQL>  select ( to_date('20200803183000','yyyymmddhh24miss') - to_date('20200803180000','yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 from dual ;

(TO_DATE('20200803183000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('20200803180000','YYYYMMDD
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                              .5
```

**Update**

@AlexPoole was right. It has to do with your `set numwith` setting

```
SQL> set numwidth 42
SQL>  select ( to_date('20200803183000','yyyymmddhh24miss') - to_date('20200803180000','yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 from dual ;

(TO_DATE('20200803183000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('20200803180000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))*24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                     .4999999999999999999999999999999999999992

SQL> set numwidth 39
SQL>  select ( to_date('20200803183000','yyyymmddhh24miss') - to_date('20200803180000','yyyymmddhh24miss') ) * 24 from dual ;

(TO_DATE('20200803183000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')-TO_DATE('20200803180000','YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'))*24
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                                                            .5
```

The NUMWIDTH setting controls the default width used when displaying numeric values. My Sqlplus was using a default 39, that is why I was seeing 0.5

Comment: I'm so sorry i want to ask this query, ```Select (to_date(atime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') -to_date(btime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))*24 From dual ``` not ```Select to_date(atime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') -to_date(btime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') From dual ``` . This post was edited, thank you!

Comment: It does not matter, the query returns 0.5

Comment: I updated the answer to show you that it returns 0.5. If you agree, please upvote and accept the answer. really appreciated

Comment: I tired one more time, but the result is same. Can you try this? ```Select CASE WHEN (to_date(atime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss') -to_date(btime, 'yyyymmddhh24miss'))*24  = 0.5 THEN 'GOOD' ELSE 'BAD' END AS RESULT From dual ```

Comment: update the question and put the output of your query and the result in sqlplus.

Comment: are you using Oracle 11g ??

Comment: I'm so sorry, the result is same. I use DBMS sql developer, and I want to know this reason not to solve this.. can you tell me the result of reason? And yes, I'm using Oracle 11g

Comment: I am afraid it has to do with SQL Developer, not a real problem in Oracle. If you run the query in SQLPLUS, you will get 0.5. You could try to run a PL/SQL block to see what happens

Comment: @RobertoHernandez - in SQL\*Plus do `set numwidth 42` and run it again... (Conversely, in SQL Developer, `set numwidth 39` and it'll return 0.5).

Comment: @AlexPoole , thank you . you are right. with default it gives me 0.5, if I changed it gives me 0.49999999999999999 .

Comment: @AlexPoole Thank you for your cooperation, I didn't know SQL*Plus settings..